# How can I disable producing paged (non-linear) skb's in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, netfilter, skb

Suppose I write some LKM with networking (netfilter) activity and I need to do some tampering with `skb` including `skb_pull()`. So I have to take care about is `skb` linear or not before pulling.
If I generally don't want to have an opportunity to face with non-linear (paged) `skb` in my system, how can I do this?
In other words: **how can I disable producing paged `skb`s in Linux kernel?**
Is there some option on network interfaces to be set up with *`ethtool`* or something else?

Comment: Did you manage to find an answer to this?

Comment: @ricebus Unfortunately nope

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer to the implementation of bpf_skb_pull_data in the kernel, this bpf helper function can pull no-linear data into linear.

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bpf-helpers.7.html